# How to set state in componentDidMount based on the response from a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am basically trying to set the state based on the response I got from an API.

api.js

```
const baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";

export const getStatus = (list) =>  {
  fetch(`${baseURL}/api/status`).then(res => {
    return res.json();
  }).then(status => {
    list.setState({status: status});
  });
};
```

And this is how I call it from a component

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {getStatus} from '../../../api';

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    getStatus(this);
  }
```

I feel like it is not a good practice to pass `this` down and modify the state from the downstream api file. Is there a more "react" way to do this?

I also tried another way, which is to wait for the callback to send back the response and then modify the state based on the response, but the `setState` function never gets executed in `componentDidMount`. If someone can direct me, that would be great!

api.js

```
const baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";

export const getStatus = () =>  {
  fetch(`${baseURL}/api/status`).then(res => {
    return res.json();
  }).then(status => {
    return status;
  });
};
```

---

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {getStatus} from '../../../api';

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    getStatus((status) => {
      this.setState({status: status});
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way is to use `.then()` in componentDidMount

api.js

```
export const getStatus = () =>  {
  return fetch(`${baseURL}/api/status`).then(res => {
    return res.json();
  });
};
```

yourComponent.jsx

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {getStatus} from '../../../api';

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    getStatus()
      .then(status => {
        this.setState({status: status});
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Making an API call and setting the state of a component based on what the call returns is normal practice in react. You don't need to pass a reference to this down to getStatus and for that matter you don't need to pass anything to getStatus. Instead, chain then off of what is returned from getStatus.

```
    componentDidMount() {
    getStatus()
      .then(status => {
        this.setState({status});
      })
  }
```

it is also unnecessary to call constructor or super in your component. Simply write:

```
class List extends React.Component {
   state = {
      status: []
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6, try the async function syntax to increase readability.

api.js

```
export const getStatus = () => fetch(`${baseURL}/api/status`);
```

yourComponent.jsx

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {getStatus} from '../../../api';

class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: [],
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await getStatus()
    this.setState({status: res.json()});
  }
```

Also, you might not need to initialize the state, and you could remove the constructor if so.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working code:

```
    fetch(serviceUrl)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(newStatus => this.setState({status: newStatus}))
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.setState({status: 'error'});
        })
```